# php array and str_replace working together

Tags: php, arrays, str-replace

```
    <?php
$search = array("cencor","cencors");
$change = array("prohibited","***");
if(isset($_POST['submit']) AND !empty($_POST['text'])){
$text = $_POST['text'];
$text = str_replace($search,$change,$text);
}
?>
<form action="index.php" method="post">
    <textarea name="text"><?php echo $text;?></textarea>
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

Hello I am using this code. I have a problem with this code that when I submit

> Don't use cencor and cencors

It returns

> Don't use prohibited and prohibiteds

I want to get result like

> Don't use prohibited and ***

How can I do that? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's something to be wary of on this front, and that is that some words are substrings of others.

I remember reading an article on the subject a few years ago, and it was titled something like "The Clbuttic Mistake". The article went into detail how a poorly implemented profanity filter can create as many problems as it solves. This particular article showed the pitfalls of exactly the same method as you are using in your question.

The replacement they focused on was naturally `$content = str_replace('ass', 'butt', $content);`. This yielded some amusing transformations, such as "assassinate" becoming "buttbuttinate".

This is exactly the same issue you are seeing, because "cencor" is a substring of "cencors". Even though you intend to replace both, you're still seeing the same problem.

The solution is to be much more targeted in the way you do your replacements, by making sure that you only match on a full word. You can do this with a regex based approach:

```
<?php

$replacements = array(
    "cencor" => "prohibited",
    "cencors" => "***"
);

$text = "Don't use cencor, and cencors";

foreach($replacements as $search => $change) {
    $text = preg_replace("~(^|[\s\W])" . preg_quote($search, '~') . "([\s\W]|$)~ism", "\\1{$change}\\2", $text);
}

echo $text;
```

Comment: It is possible to achive that with str_ireplace?

Comment: `str_ireplace` suffers from the same pitfall as `str_replace`: you can't target whole words only. Seeing your comment on one of the other answers I made sure my answer was case insensitive though - you see at the end of the first parameter of `preg_replace` I have `~ism`? The `~` is my delimiter of choice, however each of the `i`, `s`, and `m` are flags. the `i` is saying "case insensitive"